# Python If List is Empty

Tags: python

I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. I have a list and the following code:

```
def summer(position):
    sum1 = 0.0
    for line in dataFile:
        position2 = position + 1
        items = line.split(',', position2)
        items = items[position:position2]
        if len(items) < 1:
            sum1 = 0.0
        else:
            result = [float(x.strip(' "')) for x in items]
            sum1 = sum1 + sum(row for row in result)

    return sum1
```

I get the following error:

```
['offer_id']
Sum: 91383276.0
-----

['decision_id']
Sum: 215141303.0
-----

['offer_type_cd']
            result = [float(x.strip(' "')) for x in items]
    ValueError: empty string for float()
```

The value in the list is ['']
I've also tried if items == "''" or items == '' etc.

Comment: Show us the first three lines of dataFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for *individual empty items*:

```
result = [float(x.strip(' "')) for x in items if x.strip(' "')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending to include position2, then you need to create your slice from position1 to position2 + 1.

```
items = [position1:position2+1]
```

and check to see if each item in the slice is empty.